# Install usb wifi tl-wn823n on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, wlan

I need to install my TP Link USB dongle on Debian Wheezy. I already tried a bunch of different things and nothing seemed to work. Here is the result of some commands:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter

$ lsmod | grep rtl

rtl8192cu              74897  0 
rtlwifi                81393  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        52602  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              192806  3 rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              137243  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
usbcore               128741  5 ehci_hcd,usbhid,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
```

I tried installing the driver from the official Realtek website and it worked but the dongle isn't working, no result with neither `ip link` nor `ifconfig`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try adding non-free repositories and run apt-get install firmware-realtek

Comment: Have you tried installing firmware from https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware (specifically, the rtl* debs)? You might have some luck re/installing Debian from a medium that bundles the non-free packages.

Answer (score 2):

You have full support from official tp-link webpage, here is the source (to compile):

http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN823N(EU)_V2_160315_Linux.zip

http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

be careful with the hw version: you can choose v1 or v2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it worked for me):

edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

add:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

then restart the network-manager

> /etc/init.d/network-manager restart

Now it should be working

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck installing the driver due to some kernel module thing in the make / make install, but I was able to get it working by installing this package:

`install firmware-iwlwifi`

Comment: Are you sure you have the same USB device? The `iwlwifi` package provides firmware for Intel wi-fi adapters, not Realtek.